# MvvmCross View Model Initialize Complete

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

In version 5 of MvvmCross, there has been added an asynchronous Initialize override where you can do you heavy data loading.

```
public override async Task Initialize()
{
    MyObject = await GetObject();
}
```

Is there a way to determine in the View that the Initialize has completed?  Say in the View I want to set the Toolbar Title to a display a field in MyObject

```
    MyViewModel vm;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here

        this.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MyView);

        var toolbar = (Toolbar)FindViewById(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        vm = (MyViewModel)this.ViewModel;

        SupportActionBar.Title = vm.MyObject.Name;

    }
```

On the line that sets the SupportActionBar.Title, is there a way to know for sure whether the Initialize task has completed and if not, get notified when it does?

UPDATE:
I tried set two correct answers because @nmilcoff answered my actual question and @Trevor Balcom showed me a better way to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can subscribe to InitializeTask's property changes.

Something like this will work:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // your code

    ViewModel.PropertyChanged += MyViewModel_PropertyChanged;
}

private void MyViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PropertyName == nameof(ViewModel.InitializeTask) && ViewModel.InitializeTask != null)
    {
        ViewModel.InitializeTask.PropertyChanged += ViewModel_InitializeTask_PropertyChanged;
    }
}

private void ViewModel_InitializeTask_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PropertyName == nameof(ViewModel.InitializeTask.IsSuccessfullyCompleted))
        SupportActionBar.Title = ViewModel.MyObject.Name;
}
```

Of course, it could be the case that it might be easier to just listen to `ViewModel.MyObject.Name` property changes. But the above is a generic way to listen to InitializeTask property changes.

You can learn more about `InitializeTask` and `MvxNotifyTask` in the [official documentation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/mvxnotifytask).

Comment: I have tried this approach before, but the problem is that Initialize() is called before you hook the PropertyChanged event and if it finishes before you hook the event, your Event Handler never gets notified.  I had seen the MvxNotifyTask but it doesn't say how to wire it up to listen to the Initialize() Task.  I will look at InitializeTask and see if that might be the answer.

Comment: I didn't see where there is a property on a ViewModel called InitializeTask.

Comment: Never mind.  I had to update to the latest version of MvvmCross.

Comment: It did.  Thanks Bro.

Answer (score 2):

On Xamarin Forms:
I wanted to add Property Changed event login in the VM to be able to test it, so:

View.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnViewModelSet()
{
    base.OnViewModelSet();
    var vm = this.DataContext as SearchMovieViewModel;
    if (vm is null)
    {
        return;
    }

    vm.OnViewModelSet();
}
```

On your ViewModel:

```
/// <summary>
/// This method should be called in every View Code Behind when you
/// need to subscribe to InitializeTask changes.
/// </summary>
public void OnViewModelSet()
{
    if (this.InitializeTask is null)
    {
        return;
    }
    this.InitializeTask.PropertyChanged += this.InitializeTask_PropertyChanged;
}
```

Finally on your View Model implement whatever check you need to do for MvvmCross InitializeTask, in my case I used IsCompleted Property, but you can use whichever you need:

```
private void InitializeTask_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(this.InitializeTask.IsCompleted))
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Don´t forget to unsubscribe, for example when the view is destroyed. You can override this method in your View Model:

```
public override void ViewDestroy(bool viewFinishing = true)
{
        base.ViewDestroy(viewFinishing);
        this.InitializeTask.PropertyChanged -= this.InitializeTask_PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Toolbar also supports data binding the `Title` property like so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:MvxBind="Title MyObject.Name" />
```

Comment: This is a better way to do what I wanted to do.  It won't let me set but one correct answer so I had to choose the one that answered the actual question.  I am going through my code and using your method to set the heading on everything.  Thanks Bro.